# How many $7$-digit numbers can be generated with numbers in $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that all of the numbers in $S$ are used at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need to compute the following (this is not a homework or etc. just a personal curiosity). How many $7$-digit numbers can be generated with numbers in $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that all of the numbers in $S$ are used at least once?

Comment: Hint: inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: I would approach it like a process. Let the 7-digit number be of the form
$$
1~2~3~4~ A_1~ A_2~ A_3
$$
Now, you can place any number from $S$ into $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$. The number is formed. Then, you only need to think of how many rearrangements there are of this.

Comment: @MattiP.  That approach is  difficult, as a collection like $\{1,2,3,4,1,1,1\}$ has fewer permutations than does $\{1,2,3,4,1,2,3\}$.  Inclusion-Exclusion is, I think, more efficient.  Your method works, of course, but you need to break it into cases according to the nature of $A_1,A_2,A_3$.

Comment: A rephrasing of the inclusion-exclusion answer is possible by using instead [stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), yielding an answer of $4!\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}7\\4\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$.  (*I say it is a rephrasing since one of the most common approaches to deriving a formula for stirling numbers of second kind is through inclusion-exclusion in the first place*)

Comment: @lulu - There are only three partitions of $7$ into four positive integers $7=4+1+1+1=3+2+1+1=2+2+2+1$ so it is not very difficult

Comment: @Henry while true for *this* specific problem that the casework isn't so bad, one of the goals of problems like this in general is not just to get the answer for the specific values given but to learn a process that can be reused and generalized for if the values changed.  If the numbers were far larger, you would *not* want to use that approach.

Comment: Partition the set of positions into four non-empty unlabeled parts (*which will be distinguishable based on the contents of the parts*), then for part each assign which digit appears for the positions in that part.  The first step of partitioning the elements into a specific number of nonempty parts is exactly what stirling numbers of the second kind are used to count, hence the $\left\{\begin{smallmatrix}7\\4\end{smallmatrix}\right\}$.  Assigning the labels to the parts is accomplished with traditional rule of product leading to the factor of $4!$.

Comment: You say "interesting approach..." however, I must stress that this is exactly the same approach suggested by lulu and YJT using inclusion-exclusion.  The only difference is that by phrasing it with stirling numbers of the second kind, we effectively jumped straight to the result of the inclusion-exclusion rather than including the mechanics of inclusion-exclusion in our explanation.  (*That is, unless you happen to think of the definition/derivation of the stirling numbers of second kind in a different way, e.g. by recursion*)

Comment: @JMoravitz It depends on how you want to generalise the question:  if the next question was finding the answer for $11$-digit numbers with each of the four types appearing at least once, then your method would be better, but if it was to find the answer for $11$-digit numbers with each type appearing at least twice then I suspect mine might work faster

Answer (score 1):

By a brute-force counting algorithm, I obtained a total of $8400$  7-digit numbers that can be generated with the digits in $S={1,2,3,4}$ such that all of the digits are used at least once.

A possible combinatory solution for this problem is as follows. Once the four digits from $1$ to $4$ have been placed in some positions within our number, there remain three other places $A_1,A_2,A_3$ that can be filled with any  digits. We have to consider different cases for this triple.

- If $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are all equal, then our $7$-digit number includes four equal digits and three other different digits (i.e., it is obtained by rearranging a pattern of the form $aaaabcd$, where each letter can be any of the four possible digits). We can place the four equal digits in $\binom 74$ ways, and then the remaining different digits in $3!$ ways. Any of the $4$ possible digits can be that occurring four times, so the possible $7$-digits numbers in this case are

$$4\binom 743!=840$$

- If two of the three numbers $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are equal, then our $7$-digit number includes three equal digits, a pair of other equal digits, and two other different digits (i.e., it is obtained by rearranging a pattern of the form $aaabbcd$). We can place the three equal digits in $\binom 73$ ways, the successive two equal digits in $\binom 42$ ways, and then the remaining different digits in $2$ ways. The pair of digits occurring three and two times can be chosen among the possible four digits in $2\binom 42$ ways, so the possible $7$-digits numbers in this case are

$$4\binom 42 \binom 73 \binom 42=5040$$

- Lastly, if the three numbers $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are all different, then our $7$-digit number includes three pairs of equal digits and another different digit (i.e., it is obtained by rearranging a pattern of the form $aabbccd$). Let us focus on the pairs $aa$, $bb$, and $cc$. We can place the first pair of equal digits in $\binom 72$ ways, the second pair in $\binom 52$ ways, and the third in $\binom 32$ ways, leaving a single way to fill the remaining empty place with the last digit. Note that, by placing the three pairs in this manner, we accounted for all possible combinations resulting from the different order in which $aa$, $bb$, and $cc$ are inserted in the number. The triple of digits $a,b,c$  occurring in pairs can be chosen among the possible four digits in $4$ ways, so the possible $7$-digits numbers in this case are

$$4 \binom 72 \binom 52 \binom 32=2520$$

Collecting all the results we get that, as expected on the basis of the brute-force counting, the searched total number is

$$840+5040+2520=8400$$

corresponding to $\approx 51.3\%$ of all $4^7=16384$ possible $7$-digit numbers obtainable with the digits from $1$ to $4$.

Answer (score 0):

> How many $7$-digit numbers can be generated with numbers in $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that all of the numbers in $S$ are used at least once?

By the [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):
$$\underbrace{4^7}_{\text{All numbers that can be formed by }1,2,3,4}-\underbrace{\left[{4\choose 1}3^7-{4\choose 2}2^7+{4\choose 3}1^7\right]}_{\text{Numbers not having at least one of }1,2,3,4}=8400$$